# Permutations and combinations. Picking a team

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A Football/Soccer team consists of $9$ players. $2$ wingers, $2$ midfielders, $2$ strikers and three defenders. (yes I know there's no Goalkeeper.)
The coach has $11$ wingers available to him, $7$ midfielders, $5$ strikers and $9$ defenders.
How many ways can the team be selected?
I know to pick the wingers there are 
$$ \frac{11!}{2!(11-2)!} \text{ways} $$
And the same goes for the rest of the positions
But how do i find the total number of ways to pick the entire team? Do I just sum them all?
Thanks in advance

Comment: (Small typo, it should be $10$ players in the team)

Comment: There are nine.  Nine players on the team.  Count them, 2, 2, 2, and 3.  Nine!   Whahahahha! (Crackadoom!)

Comment: hahahaha sorry my bad

Comment: Woops. It appears I can't count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to combine all possibilities into one big team arrangement. All selections (winger, midflier...) are independant one from another, so you should multiply them : the answer to your problem is ${11 \choose 2}\times{7 \choose 2}\times{5 \choose 2}\times{9 \choose 3}$

---

If you want to be convinced of it, just look at this small example.
I have 2 choices for my main plate, and 3 choices for my desert. How many different menus are there?

If I pick the first main plate, I have 3 choices for desert.
If I pick the second main plate, I have 3 choices for desert.

For every choice of main plate (and there are 2 of them), I have 3 choices for desert: I actually have $2 \times 3$ choices in total. Hence, multiplication is what you're looking for.

Comment: What if the coach wanted a specific winger to be on the team?

Comment: Then, what are your remaining possibilities?

Comment: Remaining would be another winger, and then the same selection process. Would it be $$10\cdot  {7 \choose 2}\cdot {5 \choose 2}\cdot {9 \choose 3}$$

Comment: Exactly! Also, you can note that $10= {10\choose 1} $ so if you want to stick to combinatorics symbols, you can (is not necessary though, up to you)

Answer (score 1):

$${11 \choose 2}\cdot  {7 \choose 2}\cdot {5 \choose 2}\cdot {9 \choose 3}$$

You have to multiply them because, for example, for every choice of the wingers you have:

$${7 \choose 2}\cdot {5 \choose 2}\cdot {9 \choose 3}$$

possibilities for the rest of the team.

And you can apply the same idea for the others positions.